# How to give an applet shutdown privileges?

Tags: shutdown, indicator, 15.04, applet, mate

I'm using the Mate Sensor Applet (`/usr/lib/mate-sensors-applet/mate-sensors-applet`) and to prevent high temperatures I added this shutdown command:

```
shutdown -h 1
```

But it doesn't has an effect... I think it hasn't sudo/shutdown privileges.
Is there a way to assign only shutdown privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In /etc/sudoers file add a line:

```
%sudo ALL=  NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

To edit /etc/sudoers file, run visudo command.

Comment: Thank you! Finally I used: `myusername ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for this without using `sudo` everytime is giving `shutdown` command special permissions, so that if the `user` runs `shutdown` it will run with `root` permissions for this do

```
sudo chmod u+s /sbin/shutdown
```

now the `shutdown` command won't need `root` everytime you issue the command and if you wan't to revert it you can always do

```
 sudo chmod u-s /sbin/shutdown
```

and user will need to be `root` to execute `shutdown` again.